# Python Combining Data From Multiple Ranges

Tags: python-3.x

I have data set up in a terrible way (this was done before my time) and I need to consolidate it across ranges, sheets, and files.

Here's an example. I am trying to append all three of these ranges into a single table, with a column labeling which category the line item is from.
[image]

I didn't get far, but here is my current code.... This will get the entire sheet into a single, long table but also has header names of Unknown: 1-80. My idea for the process would be to isolate each category and separate them out into their own single Excel file. From there, I can append all of the resulting similar looking files. Would that be possible? The fact that everything is from left-right instead of top-down is throwing me for a loop

```
import os
import shutil
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

src = r"C:\Users\locationpath\file.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(src, sheet_name='sheetname')
df = df.iloc[14:]

dest = r"C:\Users\path\desktop\test25.xlsx"
df.to_excel(dest)

print("finished")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I'm just finding this now, and I think it's an interesting question.

```
# importing openpyxl module
import openpyxl as xl;
  
# opening the source excel file
filename ="C:\\your_path_here\\Excel_Before.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
  
# opening the destination excel file 
filename1 ="C:\\your_path_here\\Excel_After.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.active
  
# calculate total number of rows and 
# columns in source excel file
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column
  
# copying the cell values from source 
# excel file to destination excel file
for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        # reading cell value from source excel file
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
  
        # writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
  
# saving the destination excel file
wb2.save(str(filename1))



Or...
import pandas as pd
filename='C:\\your_path_here\\Excel_Before.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = 'Sheet1', skiprows = 2,  nrows= 3, usecols = 'A:M')
df

Or...
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=2, usecols='A:M')
df
```

Also,see the links below for more ideas of import data from Excel to Python.

https://pbpython.com/pandas-excel-range.html

https://pbpython.com/excel-file-combine.html

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter13/

https://towardsdatascience.com/merging-spreadsheets-with-python-append-f6de2d02e3f3